# cannot invoke initializer for type 'Object' in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Using Swift and Alamofire, I'm trying to convert a single json response in an Object ((dictionary: [String: AnyObject])) with the append method,but when I'm trying it the compiler fails throwing this error :

`cannot invoke initializer for type 'Object' with an argument list of type (dictionary:(String:AnyObject))`

Any ideas to how can I solve it?

*Important, the return of the getById function must be [Object]?*

the json response

```js
Optional(["name": object1, "_id": 5470def9e0c0be27780120d8, 
          "imageUrl": https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/api-static/objects/5470def9e0c0b_180.png,
          "location": {
                        city = Madrid;
                        country = Spain;
                        }, 
          "desc": blablablabla.
])
```

```js
class Object {

    var id: String!
    var name: String!
    var imageUrl: String!
    var location: [String: String]!

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        id         = dictionary["_id"] as? String
        name       = dictionary["name"] as? String
        imageUrl   = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String
        location   = dictionary["location"] as? [String: String]
    }
}
```

```js
func getById(completionHandler: ([Object]?, NSError?) -> ()) {
                    Alamofire.request(Router.GetById("5470def9e0c0be27780121d7")).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in

            var object = [Object]()

            var jsonObj = json as? [String: AnyObject]

            for dictionary in jsonObj!{
                object.append(Object(dictionary:dictionary))

            }
                completionHandler(object, nil)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As `jsonObj` is of type `[String: AnyObject]`, when you're trying to iterate over it, `dictionary` is of type `(String, AnyObject)`, representing a key and the value of the dictionary. That is why Swift can't instantiate your `Object`, as it requires a `Dictionary` and not a `Tuple`.

You should instantiate your `jsonObj` as `[[String: AnyObject]]`.

Some extra remarks:

1. Name your variables appropriately, `object` sounds like a single `Object`, but actually is an array of Objects. Change this to something like `objects: [Object]`
2. You are optionally downcasting in `var jsonObj = json as? [String: AnyObject]`, but then afterwards you force unwrap this variable. Either force cast it using `as!` or use an `if let` statement to catch any `nil` values.
3. Instead of looping over the values of the array, use `map` to wrap the initialiser.

So your code becomes:

```
func getById(completionHandler: ([Object]?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(Router.GetById("5470def9e0c0be27780121d7")).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in

        if let objects = json as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            completionHandler(object.map {Object(dictionary: $0)}, nil)
            return
        }
        completionHandler(nil, error)
}
```

(or something like that, I don't know what that else was doing there)

Comment: thanks vrwim, now instantiating jsonObj as `[[String: AnyObject]]` the app compiles OK but the `println("jsonObj \(jsonObj)")` is nil.

Comment: That means you're not getting a `[[String: AnyObject]]`, check the type when you enter the Alamofire `responseJSON`.

Comment: sorry vrwim, how can I check the type?, the json response I've described above.

Comment: place a breakpoint right before the line where you use it and use `print <expression>` in `lldb` to see what type it is and what it will cast to.

Comment: when I debug the `println(json)` the result is `println(json) = (AnyObject?)Some` and after when `let responseObject = json as? [String: AnyObject]`the result is `([String: AnyObject]?)<invalid>`

Comment: Check the type of `json` you get. Try to cast it to an array, see what that gives, then try to cast the first element to a dictionary, and try to figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: I've found the issue, but I don't know how can I solve it, the json response it's involved in double optional paretheses --> Optional ((json rsponse)), therefore I can't cast it in dictionary

Comment: You should unwrap it using the `if let` statement